# ImportError after setup.py

Tags: python, setuptools, importerror

I wrote a script in python (2 and 3 compatible) and want to install it using the setup.py install, so I made the following setup.py:

from setuptools import setup

```
setup(name='RedHatSecurityAdvisory',
      version='0.1',
      description='Script that automatically checks the RedHat security advisories to see if a CVE applies',
      author='<name>',
      url='<url>',
      entry_points={'console_scripts': ['rhsa = RHSA:redhatAdvisory.main']},
      packages=['RHSA'],
      license="Modified BSD license",
     )
```

The code structure is this:

```
folder
|-setup.py
|-RHSA
|  |-redhatAdvisory.py
```

redhatAdvisory.py contains a function called main

after running `sudo python / python3 setup.py install`, importing RHSA in python works, but running the command rhsa results in:

```
user@test-Dev:~/git/RedHat-Advisory$ rhsa 1212
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/rhsa", line 9, in <module>
    load_entry_point('RedHatSecurityAdvisory==0.1', 'console_scripts', 'rhsa')()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 351, in load_entry_point
    return get_distribution(dist).load_entry_point(group, name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 2363, in load_entry_point
    return ep.load()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 2088, in load
    entry = __import__(self.module_name, globals(),globals(), ['__name__'])
ImportError: No module named RHSA
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I don't see an `__init__.py` file in your `RHSA` directory; have you tried including that?

Comment: What does your installed directory look like (i.e., `/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/RHSA` or similar)?

Comment: @Evert, the __init__.py did the trick, thanks! Can you put this in an answer, so I can give you the thumbs up? :)